# How to mock Express Req and Res in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, ts-jest

I recently moved to TS and build a little microservice using Express. Used to JavaScript, where you can do whatever you want, its quite easy to test your middlewares and controller, but I fall in the very beginning using it in TS. Trying to to test a controller which is callback for the .get() method on a defined route:

```
it("should return a error message if limit and skip params are not validated", () => {
    const req = {
      query: {
        limit: "AA",
        skip: "AA",
      },
    };

    const res = {
      status: jest.fn(chainableMock),
      json: () => {},
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    const response = myController.validateQueryParams(req, res, next);
```

'req' in the last line shows a error because it does not match the express.Request type, which makes sense. I think there must be a way to go through this or maybe its a complete new scenario when testing with TS.

How can I avoid this error and hopefully keep testing the way I know? Obviously I shouldn't modify production's code typing just to test.

Comment: Cast it as Request, Response. `} as Request;`

Comment: I'd suggest you *don't* mock them, use something like Supertest that lets you actually call the endpoint. If you want more granular tests of what the endpoint does, extract a service to unit/integration test.

Comment: Had to cast it to: as any as Response, and does not throw any error and test runs, but my response is undefined when I''m expecting a Response, and acording to coverage file, test has been through that return response line. 
Anyway, thanks for your help guys!!